# How many times has a team put in to field scored a century on day 1?

Tags: cricket, statistics

In the current game between South-Africa and Sri Lanka, Sri Lanka was bowled out for 157 in 40 odd overs. Dean Elgar ended the day on 90 odd.

This made me wonder how many times in test cricket have a team fielding first managed a player with a century on day 1?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an exhaustive list at the moment, but here are two instances:

- England vs Australia 2015, Nottingham: Australia 60/10 and England end day 1 at 274/4 with Joe Root on 124*
- South Africa vs New Zealand 2013, Cape Town: New Zealand 45/10 and South Africa end day 1 at 252/3 with Alviro Petersen on 103*